# How can i use GET and POST method in Silverlight WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

How can i use GET and POST method in Silverlight WP7,

i have completed get and post method in normal asp.net application, but i don't know how to do it in silverlight with windows phone technologies

HTTP Post Method in normal asp.net

```
<form method="post" name="ePayment" action="https://www.mobile88.com/ePayment/entry.asp">
```

HTTP Get Method

```
<input type="submit" value="Proceed with Payment" name="Submit">
<input type="hidden" name="ResponseURL" value="http://localhost:2017/iPay88/response.aspx">
```

I need a solution

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            using (StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show("Using HttpWebRequest: " + resultString, "Found", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }

        }

        void SendPost()
        {
            var url = "https://www.mobile88.com/ePayment/entry.asp";

            // Create the web request object
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Start the request
            webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);




        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SendPost();
        }
        void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the stream request operation
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

            // Create the post data
            // Demo POST data 
            string postData = "data=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";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Add the post data to the web request
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the web request
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
        }

        void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response;

                // End the get response operation
                response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                response.Close();

            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                // Error treatment
                // ...
            }
        }
```

This is the code block i tried but i didn't know is this correct, guide me a correct way.

Comment: @PaulDiston Can you see my edited block

Comment: What is the error that you get?